# Equation for image mouseover pan?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

i have a simple jQ script:

1. a set width/height container
2. a landscape img (can be bigger or
   smaller than container)
3. when a user mouses over the image, it pans
   (no click/drag) until it reaches the end

The equation to move the img to the left is this:
-1(relative mouse-position)*(img width)/(container width)

This works fine, but it leaves a space one the mouse reaches the end of the img.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0zd5t1wf/2/)

```
$("figure img").mousemove( function (e) {
    var a = $(this).closest("figure"),
        b = $(this).width(),
        c = a.width(),
        d = (e.clientX - a.offset().left);
    $(this).css({
        left: -1*(d*b/c)
    }, 100);
});
```

can someone help? I want the img to be completely aligned to the right of the container once the mouse reaches the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct formula is: `-1 * (d/c) * (b - c)`

Or, more clearly: `-1 * (mouseX / figureWidth) * (imgWidth - figureWidth)`

`(mouseX / figureWidth)` represents the percent of the width of the figure that the mouse is positioned at. It will be a number between 0 and 1.

`(imgWidth - figureWidth)` represents the biggest X value you want to use to position the image at the opposite side.

Multiplying the percent by the total range of movement gives you the movement amount for the current mouse position!

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0zd5t1wf/5/)

I suggest using more descriptive variable names such as `figureWidth`, `imgWidth`, `mouseX` etc. Not only will it be easier for you to understand, but it will be easier for people to answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work: http://jsfiddle.net/0zd5t1wf/4/

i just get the limit value for the left propriety of image (the image width - the figure box)

```
$("figure img").each( function () {
    if($(this).width() >= ($(this).height() * 2.5)) {
        $(this)
            .attr("class", "panorama")
            .mousemove( function (e) {
                var a = $(this).closest("figure"),
                    b = $(this).width(),
                    c = a.width(),
                    d = (e.clientX - a.offset().left),
                    newLeft = -1*(d*b/c),
                    limitValue = parseInt($(this).width()) - parseInt($("figure").width());

                if ( newLeft < 0 && (newLeft *-1) < limitValue ){
                    $(this).css({
                        left: newLeft
                    }, 100);
                }
                $("#hello").html('why');
            });
    }
});
```